# Index into an array of values of some `enum` type in C

Tags: c, enums

The [C11 spec on enums](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.2.html)<sup>1</sup>, states that the enumerator constants must have type int (1440-1441):

> 1440 The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int.
>
> 1441 The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.107)

However, it indicates that the backing type of the enum can be either a signed int, and unsigned int, or a char, so long as it fits the range of constants in the enum (1447-1448):

> 1447 Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type.
>
> 1448 The choice of type is implementation-defined,108) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

This seems to indicate that only the compiler can know the width of an enum type, which is fine until you consider an array of enum types as part of a dynamically linked library.

Say you had a function:

```
enum my_enum return_fifth(enum my_enum[] lst) {
    return lst[5];
}
```

This would be fine when linked to statically, because the compiler knows the size of a `my_enum`, but any other C code linking to it may not.

So, how is it possible for one C library to dynamically link to another C library, and know how the compiler decided to implement the enums? (Or do most modern compilers just stick with `int`/`uint` and forgo using `char`s altogether?

<sub><sup>1</sup>Okay, I know this website is not quite the C11 standard, where as this one is a bit closer: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf</sub>

Comment: By the way, `enum my_enum[] lst` this **is not an array** and should be write `enum my_enum *lst`

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: c doesnt say how big an int is so the same question can be asked there too

Comment: The C standard doesn't say anything about static and/or dynamic linking, only about transaction units. Synchronizing object files created by different compilers is beyond C standard. And, anyway, I always ask myself such questions when I use ioctl calls with a struct argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C standard doesn't says anything about dynamical library or even static library, these concepts doesn't exist in standard. This is in the implemented behavior domain.

But as you said nothing prevent a compiler to use different type for an enumeration, this mean the one compiler can use a type and another use a different type.

> This would be fine when linked to statically

In fact no, let say that A is a compiler that used `char` and B is a compiler that used `int`, and let say these types are not the same size. You compile a static library with the A compiler, and you statically link this library to a program compiled by B. This is static and still, B can't know that A doesn't use the B type for the enum.

> So, how is it possible for one C library to dynamically link to another C library

Well, as I said this is not possible for static library, for the same reason, this is not possible for dynamic library.

> Or do most modern compilers just stick with int/uint and forgo using chars altogether?

Big compiler generally talk between them to use the same rules on the same environment, yes. But nothing in C guaranty this behavior. (On the compatibility problem: a lot of people use "The C ABI", despite the fact it doesn't exist in the standard.)

So the best advice is to compile your dynamic library with the same compiler and option that compile your main program, also check the documentation of your compiler is a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

The complete definition of the `enum` needs to be visible at the time it is used.  Then the compiler will know what the size will be.

Forward declarations of `enum` types is not allowed.

Comment: But couldn't two compilers pick different sizes for the same enum code, even if its been declared in a header file?

Comment: That is, an enum with two constants for `0` and `1` can pick either an `int` as its backing, or a `char`.